# How do I create iOS7 gradients?

Tags: color, gradient

I'm searching for some techniques that offer similarities to the new Apple blurred gradient backgrounds. One of my clients is requesting a similar look to the new iOS, while I have some blurry photo graphic backgrounds they failed to capture the subtleties of the new OS.

The blending tool can create some very stylized gradients, however my lack of talent/expertise makes the majority of my attempts look messy. Any links fellow creators?

[iOS 7 Color Stack](http://ios7colors.com)

Comment: Blending tool in what??? Can't you simply sample the gradients in the link you provided?

Comment: Blending in Illustrator. Example: http://dribbble.com/shots/1278274-Weather-Jams-Stream?list=158011-Weather-Jams

Comment: Found an anser: http://tutvid.com/ios7-interface-photoshop-cs6-tutorial/

Comment: @Charles Maybe you could add the main instructions to an answer (it's ok to answer your own questions). Otherwise, this will remain as unanswered.

Comment: So were you looking for an answer for Illustrator, Photoshop, or either?

Comment: Either. Although, I prefer what is the simplest and least amount of time/steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the tutorial you posted in your comment has instructions for an [entire iOS 7 interface](http://tutvid.com/ios7-interface-photoshop-cs6-tutorial/), here are the steps for the gradient as asked in your question:

> **Gradients For Icons (Step 22)**
>
> -- Ahh the beauty of brightly colored, sharply graduated icons! We’re going to stay true to what we’re seeing with the iOS7 beta and place
> those colorful gradients on the icons. Select the first icon in the
> Layers panel and go <kbd>Layer > Layer Style > Gradient Overlay</kbd>. Check out my
> screenshots to see what gradients I am using for the four icons.
>
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

[See the full tutorial](http://tutvid.com/ios7-interface-photoshop-cs6-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for the techniques and fine-tuning the area of interest.